# Using cache with spring boot and redis embeded

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I want to use spring boot with caching data retrieved from rest web service.
I propose to use redis for caching data. Is it possible to use embeded redis with spring boot without installing a redis software?
If yes with which version of spring boot and how to do it?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: There's no such thing? All the embedded redis frameworks are for integration test. Use an in-memory solution for caching there are some more verbose like Ehcache that could be used if you want more caching control like TTL.

Comment: Thanks Darren! So with Ehcache, it is possible to use cache without installing any software. and i want to know if ehcache offer the possibilty to enable and disable cache?

Answer (score 1):

Redis can't meet your request.

You can of course simply use embedded `EhCache` within your Spring Boot application. If you want to share the cache, it depends on your architecture. You could expose REST endpoints to make you cache available to other applications.

You can refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache.

Spring have annotation `@EnableCaching` to enable or disable cache. Also, there are four annotations like `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` to custom the cache logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast supports the scenario you are trying to implement. It has a concept of embedded cache that can be shared/synchronized across the service nodes.

For more details see:

- https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-cache/
- https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-use-embedded-hazelcast-on-kubernetes/